# DataOutputStream over TCP works faster when creating a new socket for every message

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

While trying to create a simple Android app that allows me to send a simple string to an IoT device, I used code which initialised a new socket everytime it would send a string. I thought it would be better to have a socket send multiple strings before it would get closed again, but this turned out to be very slow. I am not experienced enough to realise what is going on here.

```
public class sendString extends AsyncTask<String, String, Socket> {
int brightness;
private int oldbrightness;
void changeBrightness(int newbright){
    oldbrightness = brightness;
    brightness = newbright;
}
@Override
protected Socket doInBackground(String... strings) {
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(strings[0], 80);
        socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
        DataOutputStream DOS = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
        while (!isCancelled()) {
            if (oldbrightness != brightness) {
                DOS.writeUTF("\"sr1\":" + brightness + " ");
                DOS.flush();
            }
        }
        socket.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
protected void onCancelled(){
    return;
}
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress){

}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Socket socket){
    return;
}
```

}

This is my code which sends multiple strings over one socket. The function is called when a seekbar is clicked, brightness is changed everytime the seekbar moves and cancel(true) is called when the seekbar is released. Is my code wrong or is there a different reason as to why this method would be so slow?

The old code:

```
public class sendString extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Socket> {
@Override
protected Socket doInBackground(String... strings) {
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(strings[0], 80);
        DataOutputStream DOS = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        DOS.writeUTF(strings[1]);
        socket.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}
This would get called everytime the seekbar moved.

Comment: I just edited my orignal post to contain the other version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the first version executes in a CPU-smoking loop sending messages infinitely, while the second version executes exactly once per seek bar move, which should always be quicker.

You are comparing apples and oranges.

You should open the socket *outside* this method, prior to installing the seekbar listener, and only send one message per invocation.